# How can I convert a string in a textfield to an Int in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, textfield, swift5

I tried for a long time to turn the text into an `Int` but it did not work. I tried it like this:

(`AnzahlString` is a textfield)

```
var AnzahlAInt = 0

if let AnzahlAString = AnzahlString.text {
    let AnzahlAInt = Int(AnzahlAString)
}
```

But then I always get the error:

> Value of optional type 'Int?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Int'

Then I added a `!` at the end of `Int(AnzahlAString)!` so I don't get a error, but now when I press on the button, the app crashes. It was predictable, but how can I change this now to an `Int` without the `!`?

Comment: `AnzahlString` is a bad name of anything which is not a String.

Comment: `if let value = Int(anzahlString.text!) {anzahlAInt = value}` or `var anzahlAInt =  Int(anzahlString.text!) ?? 0`. The `text` property is safe to force unwrapp. Also variable names should start with a lowercase letter

Comment: Property names should be snakeCase. Only Type names should start with a capitalisation.

Comment: `UITextField` text property default value is an empty string. It will NEVER return `nil`. Even if you assign `nil` to it then get its value it will return an empty string. You can safely force unwrap its value `text!`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, it looks like you have two things to check for:

- is `AnzahlString.text` present, and
- does it represent an `Int`

The first check is in fact not necessary, since `.text` will never return nil, even though it's marked as Optional. This means you can safely force-unwrap it.

The second check is easily done by using the `??` operator:

```
let AnzahlAInt = Int(AnzahlString.text!) ?? 0
```

PS, just as a stylistic hint: variable names in Swift ususally start with a lowercase letter, names starting with capital letters are used for types.

PPS: your code as written shadows `AnzahlAInt` - the value of your var is never changed.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the resulting `Int` is optional, is that parsing might or might not succeed. For example, if you try to parse the string "Fluffy Bunnies" into an `Int`, there is no reasonable `Int` that can be returned, therefore the result of parsing that string will be `nil`.

Furthermore, if you force the parser by using `!`, you're telling Swift that you know for sure that the string you pass will always result in a valid `Int`, and when it doesn't, the app crashes.

You need to handle the situation in which the parse result is `nil`. For example:

```
if let AnzahlAIntResult = Int(AnzahlAString) {
    // We only get here if the parse was successful and we have an Int.
    // AnzahlAIntResult is now an Int, so it can be assigned to AnzahlAInt.
    AnzahlAInt = AnzahlAIntResult
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did a good job so far but missed out one thing.

> This line **tries to** convert the String into an Int. However this can fail, since your String can be something like this `"dfhuse"`.

```swift
let AnzahlAInt = Int(AnzahlAString)
```

This is why the result of `Int(AnzahlAString)` is an Optional (`Int?`). To use it as an real `Int`, you have to **unwrap it**.

First solution is the `!`, however, every time this does fail your app crashes. Not a good Idea to use so.

> The best solution would be Optional Binding, as you already used to get the text of your text field.

```swift
if let AnzahlAString = AnzahlString.text {

    if let safeInt = Int(AnzahlAString) {
        // You can use safeInt as a real Int
    } else {
        print("Converting your String to an Int failed badly!")
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free to ask again if something is unclear.

Comment: `UITextField` text property default value is an empty string. It will NEVER return `nil`. Even if you assign `nil` to it then get its value it will return an empty string. You can safely force unwrap its value `text!`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for your answer. That true, however the question by ID-Temir was about the Optional Handling for the Integer Conversion, so I didn't want to confuse him with this additional change in his code.

Answer (score 0):

For unwrapping you can also use guard like this

Simple and easy

```
guard let AnzahlAInt = Int(AnzahlString.text!) else {
            return
        }

        print(AnzahlAInt)
```